# create a link_to in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I need to pass a notice to a view from controller, and I want if can to create some link also to the notice.

My controller:

```
format.html { redirect_to purchase_order_headers_path, notice: 'PO already has RR with RR ID: ' + rr.rr_id + ', void RR first.' }
```

Is there any way so I can do it so the `[rr.rr_id]` will become a link so when the user click on it will go to it's page? Since `link_to` will return error `"undefined method"` if put on controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if you are using rails 3, you can use `view_context.link_to(...)` in your controller.

UPDATE: with the format.html code

```
format.html do
  redirect_to purchase_order_headers_path, notice: "PO already has RR with RR ID: #{view_context.link_to(rr.rr_id, receiving_record_header_path(rr.id))} void RR first.".html_safe
end
```

Comment: Why when I use `view_context.link_to()` return it's own action? give me `<a href="/purchase_order_headers/1/status_void">RR-1301-0001</a>`, but I need to be `<a href="/receiving_record_headers/1/">RR-1301-0001</a>`

Comment: that was just an example.  you have to use pass arguments to link_to. for example, that link you want, you write that as `view_context.link_to('RR-1301-0001','/receiving_record_headers/1')`.  you can, of course, use named routes for the url :)

Comment: It done sir, and result `PO already has RR with RR ID: +"<a href="/receiving_record_headers/1">RR-1301-0001</a>"+, void RR first.`, haha where do I mistake? This is my last code `format.html { redirect_to purchase_order_headers_path, notice: 'PO already has RR with RR ID: ' + ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(rr.rr_id, receiving_record_header_path(rr.id)).html_safe + ', void RR first.' }`

Comment: Sorry I mean `PO already has RR with RR ID: <a href="/receiving_record_headers/1">RR-1301-0001</a>, void RR first.`

Comment: see my updated answer. it's hard to read html code here in the comments

Comment: It had done nicely, thank!. But why single quote and double quote make a big different here? should I make another question about it?

Comment: `'++' + another_string + '++'` is slower than "++#{another_string}++" because it creates 3 strings instead on 1. just saying :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `#{ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to 'rr.rr_id', '/url'}.html_safe`

To make link in your controllers.
To have the string display as html (instead of being escaped), call the html_safe method on the string

Comment: I fail to convert that to be a HTML tag sir, i confuse then about it. Sorry, I kind of rails newbie sir. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Actually the final result that I try with `format.html { redirect_to purchase_order_headers_path, notice: 'PO already has RR with RR ID: ' + ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(rr.rr_id, receiving_record_header_path(rr.id)).html_safe + ', void RR first.' }` also the same result on html like what I comment on @jvnill answer, where do I mistake?