# How can I use link_to in application_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to parse some text and link certain strings that come from various models and is headed to a couple of different views.  I though application_helper.rb was the right place to put this. (Still a rookie at figuring out where best to code things).

application_helper.rb

```
def link_buffs(text)
    Buff.all.each do |b|
      text = text.gsub('[' + b.name + ']',link_to('[' + b.name + ']', b, class: b.name + '-buff buff')).to_s
    end
    return text
  end
```

sample buff data

```
buff.id:integer
buff.name = 'Poison'
```

sample text `Places a 5% [Poison] debuff`

And in the views, I'm calling `link_buffs(string).html_safe` in a few different places. But it appears to be silently failing and all I can figure out right now is that link_to isn't available in the helper.

So the question is how do I make link_to available in the helper or should I be putting this code somewhere else?

Comment: What does `test` look like? (A sample would suffice.) What does at least one instance of `Buff` look like? Have you tried `pry`ing in `link_buffs`?

Comment: I added the requested info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:
`ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to()`

There are other answers to this question: [create a link_to in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996113/create-a-link-to-in-controller)

Comment: The solution you linked to doesn't work for me  I get `undefined local variable or method `view_context' for #<#<Class` and when I use `ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to()` I get an exception `arguments passed to url_for can't be handled`  So I built out the url manually as opposed referencing the object and it works.

Comment: Now the question is how do I reference the object in the url_for to future proof this a little more?

Comment: You could add a method in a helper file that uses the url_for method. That way it should be accessible in your controller

Comment: The ultimate solution was to call for  ...  `ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to('[' + b.name + ']', buff_path(b)` ...